# How can I get turtles to breed once during a defined breeding season?

Tags: netlogo

In my model I have males and females. They can breed with each other to produce offspring at a specific tick every 365th day.

How can I get the adults to turn off the ability to breed once they reproduce but regain the ability the following breeding season.

```
ask females [
    if  age > 0 and age mod 365 = 0 [
  reproduce
    ]
.
.
.
to reproduce 
    if count mates > 0   [ ; the number of males in a defined radius 
    hatch fecundity [
    set mother myself
    set father one-of [mates] of mother
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to create a variable that counts the number of days since they last bred. Then increment that variable each tick. Then reset it once the female successfully reproduces. Something like (not tested):

```
females-own [days-since-child]

to go
  ...
  ask females [ set days-since-child days-since-child + 1 ]
  ask females with [days-since-child >= 365] [ reproduce ]
  tick
end

to reproduce 
  if any? mates > 0   [ ; the number of males in a defined radius
    set days-since-child 0 
    hatch fecundity [
      set mother myself
      set father one-of [mates] of mother
    ]
  ]
end
```